# Mail merge template : local variable not getting value in if..else

Tags: mailmerge, aspose.words

{ MERGEFIELD TableStart:Test}{ SET PLAN {MERGEFIELD Name}="XYZ" "1" "0"}}
{ MERGEFIELD TableEnd:Test }

{ IF { REF PLAN } = "1" "Pass" "Fail"}

In this example always getting result Fail, whether Name is "XYZ" or not.

can anyone suggest further ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case in the SET field you should use IF field to evaluate condition. Please see the following field codes:

```
{ SET PLAN { IF {MERGEFIELD Name} = XYZ "1" "0"} }
{ IF { REF PLAN } = "1" "Pass" "Fail" }
```

After executing simple mail merge using the following code:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");
doc.MailMerge.Execute(new string[] { "Name" }, new string[] { "XYZ" });
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

The resulting document has the following field codes:

```
{ SET PLAN XYZ = XYZ "1" "0"} }
{ IF { REF PLAN } = "1" "Pass" "Fail" }
```

which is properly evaluated with "Pass" text.

Also in MS Word document field whitespaces matters. See the screenshot from MS Word document on my side

[image]